# aquire frames with pymba open-cv cv2 imshow()

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera

I am trying to display a continous video stream of a camera. i am using the pymba SDK. included is an example of how to display a video stream.
running "opencv_acquire_streaming_images.py" does exactly what i need to do. the problem now is, when you run it the first time, its fine. if you run it the second time without restarting the kernel it doesnt. code runs, no errors but no images are streamed.
I recon it's a problem with open-cvs imshow function that requires the waitKey function aftewards. i have not managed to find a working solution. I would be very grateful for any help.

The example Code is:

```
from time import sleep
from pymba import Vimba
from examples.camera._display_frame import display_frame

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Vimba() as vimba:
        camera = vimba.camera(0)
        camera.open()

        # arm the camera and provide a function to be called upon frame ready
        camera.arm('Continuous', display_frame)
        camera.start_frame_acquisition()

        # stream images for a while...
        sleep(5)

        # stop frame acquisition
        # start_frame_acquisition can simply be called again if the camera is still armed
        camera.stop_frame_acquisition()
        camera.disarm()

        camera.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interrupt handler 'display_frame', an cv window is opened but never closed. So you just have to put a

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

at the end of your code and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP. Also check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.